# How would I update these rules so both can run in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm needing to merge both of these inside my .htaccess folder. If the top one runs, WordPress works properly but my forum does not. If the bottom one runs it's reversed. I've done some research and I found it's because I have multiple RewriteBases in the code. I'm needing some help getting them merged together though. Thank you.

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|map)(\?|$) /forum/404error.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /forum/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. This is at least working for me.

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forum/api/.* index.php [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^forum/\.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico|map)(\?|$) /forum/404error.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forum/. /forum/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```